# Files with the same name in a TextMate project

Tags: macos, textmate

One of the few things that bothers me about TextMate is that it can be difficult to differentiate between files that share the same name in a project, e.g:

[alt text http://img530.imageshack.us/img530/6791/bild1r.png](http://img530.imageshack.us/img530/6791/bild1r.png)

In this case, the file on the right is located in the project relative path model/realtimemodel.py, while the other file contains unit tests for that code. Sure, you can command-click the name in the title bar to see a directory list, but it feels sub-optimal. What I would like is something along the lines of:

[alt text http://img240.imageshack.us/img240/1783/bild3.png](http://img240.imageshack.us/img240/1783/bild3.png)

This gives a quick at-a-glance idea of what file you're working on. Has anyone seen any plugin or bundle that makes this possible?

Edit: [Here is a ticket](http://ticket.macromates.com/show?ticket_id=B3D5CCFC) in Macromates tracker that requests this feature (although I would prefer a project-relative path).

Answer (score 3):

This is a start: http://snipplr.com/view/11490/textmate-command-snippet--show-document-path-in-window-title/

Answer (score 1):

I think [vasi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68780/vasi)'s solution is the closest you can get to what you want (+1 for him)
I don't think that the bundle can be automatically ran on open, and also, the title changes back to default when switching between tabs, so even if it could, it would be useless.

I've searched for a defaults key (like the one from Finder, *_FXShowPosixPathInTitle* editable with

```
defaults write com.apple.finder _FXShowPosixPathInTitle -bool YES)
```

but there isn't any. Here's [the list of available keys](http://manual.macromates.com/en/expert_preferences.html) for Textmate.

Maybe you can write feature request somewhere as it is very useful and not so hard to impletement.

Comment: There are a couple of threads on the developer's mailing list, but apparently it's not implemented yet. I agree with you that this could be an optional plist key.

http://lists.macromates.com/textmate/2005-February/003038.html

Comment: I didn't know that. Nice question anyway.